# ffmpeg image and flask app in two different containers in Docker compose. How do I use ffmpeg in flask app?

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, docker-compose

Here is my docker compose yml file:

```
ffmpeg:
    image: jrottenberg/ffmpeg:ubuntu
    tty: true
flask_app:
  build: ./flask_app
  #image: conorquinn01/composeapp
  command: python ./flask_app/app.py
  ports:
   - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
   - .:/muse_compose2
  links:
    ['ffmpeg']
```

Not sure how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a noob with Docker and python isn't my language but I'm facing a similar problem. I have a rails app to save videos with shrine on docker and I don't want the transcoding in the same container because of the local resources, so, when somebody upload a video I save the ID in the BD and the video is sent to the shared folder while a thread call the ffmpeg container (jrottenberg/ffmpeg:ubuntu). If you're interested, here is the script to run the ffmpeg while saving in the shared folder:

**Windows**

```
docker run -it -v c:/Users/[your-user]/desktop/compartida:/v jrottenberg/ffmpeg -i http://archive.org/download/thethreeagesbusterkeaton/Buster.Keaton.The.Three.Ages.ogv /video.mp4
```

**Linux**

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd):/v jrottenberg/ffmpeg -i http://archive.org/download/thethreeagesbusterkeaton/Buster.Keaton.The.Three.Ages.ogv  /video.mp4
```

And the link to the git of the project
[jrottenberg/ffmpeg](https://github.com/jrottenberg/ffmpeg)

Because I make a folder with the video ID to save the videos, when I want the video I just use the id in the BD instead of the name. **I'm sorry for my english**.